# Is Quartz.Net still being updated? If not any alternatives?

Tags: quartz.net

I am looking at [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) and it seems to be almost a year ago.

I am wondering if they stopped development on it or it the next versions is just taking a while to do?

I am asking this because I really don't like to invest time in something that is at the end of its life or not being developed on anymore because I just know in the future I going to have to upgrade to something different so might as well just start with something else.

Of course whatever I choose might not be developed on in the future either but I like to see new versions to be a few months within the time I start to use that product.

If it is dead anyone have any other alternatives that are being still worked on and have the same features as Quartz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz.net is actually very active. I've written to @lahma a couple of time for bugs and he fixed it in a very short time.
A couple of months ago I had tried the 2.0 and it was a little bit buggy.
I know there's a new API. You might give it a go.

Answer (score 9):

Quartz.NET development hasn't stopped **at all**, it just moved to [github](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet). If you check the [source repository at sourceforge](http://quartznet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/quartznet/), the last commit was 4 months ago and it clearly says "Source moved to GitHub, removing trunk as it's misleading at the moment".

The github repository has currently 28 watchers and 8 forks, and active contributors (i.e. it's not a one-man show) so the project is definitely not going to die any time soon.

By the way, the latest release was 1.0.3 (August 2010), at the time of this writing this is much less than a year ago.

Comment: I am just going of the main page. I mean they could put something on the main page and say "hey we moved" or Version 2.0 is happening or whatever.

Comment: @chobo2: I think you should be telling that to @lahma (Quartz.NET author and maintainer) at github... I'm just another Quartz.NET user, not part of the dev team.