# Quartz.NET: is it used by any known company?

Tags: c#, .net, scheduler, quartz.net

I am thinking about adopting it. The website somewhat confusing me saying it targets only .NET 1.1, which is way out-of-date. So I am wondering if it's actually actively used product or just another port similar to Hadoop.NET, existing but barely used.

This question [Is Quartz.Net still being updated? If not any alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931123/is-quartz-net-still-being-updated-if-not-any-alternatives) addresses the issue if Quartz.NET is being actively developed. I am mostly wondering about any serious use of it.

Comment: The website says "targets Framework version 1.1 **and above**" (emphasis added). It never says "only .NET 1.1".

Comment: A bit below that, in the 1.0.3 release announcement, it clearly says "This release supports .NET 1.1., 2.0 and 3.5 SP1, there is still no official support for .NET 4.0 but you should have no problems running Quartz.NET with .NET 4.0 using the binaries compiled for framework 3.5."

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: sorry. You are right, it says so. I suppose I should have said 1.1 had a lot less features that 3.5 and 4.0 did (like Parallel and LINQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adopted it for my customers.
At the beginning I was reluctant cause the project seemed old and dead but then, I tried to do a few things and, what can I say, it works.
Version 1.0.3 works great and, it seems, bug free.
Since I always want to use to latest-versions-of-everything I tried the 2.0 (they've put together a new API) but there were some bugs on the database side.
I know Marko Lahma is [working](https://github.com/lahma/quartznet) actively on it.

Comment: Why did it seem old and dead? What gave you that impression (so that it can be corrected)?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: because when I've starting using it (5 4 months ago) there was just 1.0.3 released in August 2010. I had tried version 2.0 but it was really buggy. The AdoJobStore wasn't working at all. I sent a couple of emails to Marko Lahma and he replied and fixed the issues in a few day. I am not complaining. I am very happy with the project and I would recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

My current customer uses it in a smaller project as an internal scheduler.

It could be considered niche though (Ed:subjective), as you wouldn't use it as often as a ORM, so naturally a lot less people implement it.

Comment: That quartz.net is a niche product- not many applications use scheduling. An ORM (data access) is used way more often than a scheduler (as percentage of software written).

Answer (score 1):

According to this, it is ALIVE
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet

Answer (score 0):

I know this company uses it in their product: http://www.kmssoftware.com/ It works....

Answer (score 0):

At least based on this blog from ebay (2016), Quartz is being used actively by ebay.
https://tech.ebayinc.com/engineering/performance-tuning-on-quartz-scheduler/

The project is active and is now being used widely.